# Export video from Adobe Animate using Js/Greensock

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, gsap, animate-cc

I have a Adobe Animate CC Canvas file. I'm using greensock to control all the animation in the project, so NO timeline animation. I would like to export the file as a video, and have Adobe media encoder convert it into the format that I need. Right now the only thing that gets exported is the start of the animaiton, but the JS is never ran during the export process. I was able to do this when I used AS3, but this is the first time I'm trying to do the same thing but using a canvas file. Is this even possible to achieve with Adobe Animate CC?